# Canadian ETA - does upper/lower case in my name matter?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, eta

I have recently applied for a Canadian ETA and been approved, but I've noticed that my name in the application form was in lower case while on my passport it is in upper case.

Does this matter?

Answer (score 7):

If the name itself is correct, don't overthink this.

Your name isn't a password and is **not** case-sensitive